# How to you prove that n*log n is in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am working on Big-Oh, but I stuck on the proving part.

Question is to prove

n*log n is in O(n).

Given that there is a formula to check if it is in big-Oh
I tried

F(n) <= c*g(n)

n*log n <= 1*n

Then I got log(n) <= 1 , where n>n0. So if I substitute 100 to n, the result is bigger than 1.

(I checked the answer the function is in O(n))

Comment: It's kind of hard to prove something that isn't true. O(nlogn) algorithms are not O(n) algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it is **not** in `O(n)` pretty easily.

Assume the claim is true, so by [definition of big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition):

> There are constants N, c such that for all n > N > 0: n log n <= c*n

```
n log n <= c*n  since n > 0
log n <= c
n <= 2^c
```

But for `n = max {2^c+1, N+1}` - the above does not hold true. Thus the initial assumption is wrong, and there are no such constants.

If there are no such constants, by definition of big O notation, `n log n` is NOT in `O(n)`.

Comment: Does not log have base 10 or ln e ?

Comment: @Tom I assumed base 2, but that doesn't really matter to the concept of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove n*log n is O(n), because it isn't.

At least one flaw in your proof is that n * log n <= 1*n is not true.